# Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.javatuples.Pair]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, request

Am trying to pass `javatuples.Pair` type over the request url and getting the exception. Not user whether am passing it properly or not.

Please find my code below :

```
public <T> T getUserToNotifyDeactivationByRole(List<Pair<String, Integer>> rolePair, Class<T> responseType) {
      String href = securityOptions.linkTo("users").concat(format("/notifyUserDeactivationByRole?rolePair=%s", join(rolePair, ',')));
      return restTemplate.getForEntity(href, responseType).getBody();
  }
```

Please find the error logs below :

```
exception : Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.javatuples.Pair]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.javatuples.Pair]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I have used `join` in another requirement. (from apache.commons.lang3)

```
public <T> T getUser(List<String> districtIds, Class<T> responseType) {
    String href = securityOptions.linkTo("users").concat(format("/get-userlist-by-createaccess?districtIds=%s", join(districtIds, ',')));
    return restTemplate.getForEntity(href, responseType).getBody();
  }
```

Comment: @LutzHorn - am not very sure., this is the first time am using `Pair` and passing as parameter.

Comment: OK. But what is `join`, how is it imported? Is `href` what you expect? And what is the value of `responseType`?

Comment: Its from `apache.commons.lang3`

Comment: I have updated one more example for `join()`

Comment: Can you debug and check the value of `href` in your first code snippet? Does it look like you expect?

Comment: you mean., where i used `Pair` that i have to check?

Comment: Yes, this one please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197342/discussion-between-karthikeyan-and-lutz-horn).

Answer (score 0):

The getForEntity method apparently cannot convert the response to a Pair, however, you can try to get the response as String and then convert the String to the pair manually. Rest template does not know how to map the obtained response to a Pair.

If you use Jackson for deserialization, you can try to add mixins the way how it is done here:
https://github.com/javatuples/javatuples/issues/3#issuecomment-390901512